# Find Unique Tags in an XML file

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have an XML file which contains the tag `<image_file_name>`, this tag repeats and occasionally this value is duplicated, I am trying to find the total number of unique instances values of `<image_file_name>`.

```
$simpleXML = simplexml_load_file("stock_availability.xml");

$uniqueProducts = array();

foreach ($simpleXML->product as $product) {
    $image_file_name = $product->image_file_name;
    if(in_array($image_file_name, $uniqueProducts)) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        $uniqueProducts[] = $image_file_name;
        echo 2;
    }
$image_file_name = null;
}

echo count($uniqueProducts);
```

The `count()` returns the total number of instances of `image_file_name` not unique instances.

`2` is also echoed continuously and `1` is never echoed.

Comment: I assume this is because of a little mistake you made, you need to cast the simlexmlelement to string first so you get a value you can use to check uniqueness. Otherwise you would be looking for the simplexmlelement which is unique, always. But the string representing it's element value is not unique. `$image_file_name = (string) $product->image_file_name;` - Take care with trouble-shooting, double check expectations at various points when you hunt down such errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've stared at your code for a few minutes and cannot see a problem. I take it you've used a print_r($uniqueProducts) and have found duplicates in the output.

Have you checked for whitespace or case differences in the otherwise duplicate entries? 
Try using some standardising - e.g by using strtoupper(trim()) and quotes.

e.g.:

```
$simpleXML = simplexml_load_file("stock_availability.xml");

$uniqueProducts = array();

foreach ($simpleXML->product as $product) {
    $image_file_name = $product->image_file_name;
    $dup_check=strtoupper(trim($image_file_name));
    if(in_array("$dup_check", $uniqueProducts)) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        $uniqueProducts[] = "$dup_check";
        echo 2;
    }
$image_file_name = null;
}

print_r($uniqueProducts);
echo "<br>".count($uniqueProducts);
```

See if this helps any.